# How can I retrieve the slug for a custom post type via name?

Tags: custom-post-types, slug, custom-post-type-archives

How can I retrieve the slug for a particular custom post type via its name? I would appreciate some assistance.

Comment: Aren't these functions `wp_get_post_terms` & `get_term_by` any use for you?

Comment: @sri Those functions seem to be related to individual posts and taxonomies. I don't see how I can use them for my purposes.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Then please share your code...

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution: get_post_type_archive_link( $post_type );

Instead of providing a slug, it retrieves the archive url for a designated custom post type.

e.g.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'books' ); ?>">Movies Archive</a>
```